# How to export use case diagram in visual studio 2010 as image?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

How to export use case diagram in visual studio 2010 as image?
jpg or other image to Microsoft word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For start you can export it via Print Screen (if diagram is not too big, of course), crop image via [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/)(or your other favourite image editor), save as JPG and you are done.

Answer (score 2):

Even faster, you could select all the items and copy, you can paste a nice fitting image in a document or image editor.